# Selenium WebDriver C# : Timeout exception when running multiple tests even after using Explicit Wait

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Even after adding wait, I get the time out error when running multiple test cases. 
AddTest test case with AddMaterial() passed.
SearchTest test case with AddMaterial() and SearchMaterial() failed. Throws exception at saveComments click of AddMaterial().

Page Object:

```
  namespace ProjectName.PageObjects
    {
           class AddPage
           { 
              public void AddMaterial()
              {
                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
                IWebElement saveComments =  wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("submitRequest")));
                saveComments.Click();
                IWebElement stat = wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//*[text()='Status']")));
                Console.WriteLine(stat.Text);
              }
         }
    }
```

Test Class:

```
namespace ProjectName
{
    class AddTestClass
    {
        IWebDriver driver;
        AddPage add;
        SearchPage search;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {            
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
               //Go to URL
               //Login
        }

        [Test]
        public void AddTest()
        {
            add.AddMaterial();
        }

        [Test]
        public void SearchTest()
        {
            add.AddMaterial();
            search.SearchMaterial();
        }
}
}
```

I am getting the following exception:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:61166/session/42df692cc47c0f496c543b722252b129/element/a0a28151-31be-4c9e-9f22-717ca31925dc/click timed out after 60 seconds.'
>
> Inner exception:
>   WebException: The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.

Comment: Which browser are you testing with? Which version of the browser? Which version of its web driver are you using?

Comment: Google Chrome Version 81.0.4044.129 (Official Build) (64-bit), Selenium WebDriver 3.141.0,  Chrome Driver 81.0.4044.6900.                                                                      
 It was working fine before. Issue happened after a change which led to increase in loading time after the 'Save Comments'